# Matching the nearest or closest string values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup, vlookup

I have two excel file wihch contains data like

**file_1.xlsx**

```
Dist  Vill  con.no  val1 val2 val3 val4 val5 val6 val7 val8 ...
 ko   satn    1     14    2    2    5    12   17   56   3
 ko   barn    1     15    8    5    3    17   90   45   12
 ko   **piks**    2    null null null null null null null null
 ko   **tran**    1    null null null null null null null null
 .     .      .      .    .   .    .    .     .    .    .
 .     .      .      .    .   .    .    .     .    .    .
```

**file_2.xlsx**

```
State  Name  pr.no val1 val2 val3 val4 val5 val6 val7 val8 ...
 SO    barn   1    15    8    5    3    17   90   45   12                                           
 SO    kath   1    40    19   79   5    12   65   40   30
 SO    **paks** 2  89    2    0    45   98   45   4    7
 SO    satn   1    15    78   62   0    6    1    8    69
 SO    **trim**   1    19   79    5    40   19   79   0    9
 .      .     .     .    .    .     .   .     .   .    .
 .      .     .     .    .    .     .   .     .   .    .
```

so I have to lookup for the values in file_2.xlsx to populate the data into file_1.xlsx, if the value matches exactly then it returns the data else it gives null values so for the unmatched values I have to manually look into file_2.xlsx for the nearest match and copy that name and paste into file_1.xlsx so that it will populate the matches. It's very tedious task because the data is too large in both the file.Can I have a function which gives me the nearest values .Right now I'm using the following function

```
=VLOOKUP($B$1:$B$13025,'[file_2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$val1:$valn,COLUMN()+(-1),FALSE)
```

this is what I have refered for the nearest match function but not getting the output.
[reference](http://trumpexcel.com/2014/06/find-closest-match-in-excel/)

any help on this would be much appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Is **piks** supposed to return values from **paks** and **tran** from **trim**?

Comment: @Pomul yes piks supposed to return values from paks and tran from trim.

Comment: And likewise I have many other names which I want to be matched to its nearest string

Comment: Unless there is a pattern that you can use in a logical sequence, this is way out of my league! From your sample data, it doesn't look like there is an easy pattern I can use. Your similar strings only seem to share the first character and unless there is no duplication of the first character in your whole list (which seems unlikely) I think it is going to be difficult to achieve what you are seeking. That being said, I'm at best a beginner user with VBA, so may be there is something to do with that. You hsould add VBA to the tags of your question if that can be a solution for you.

Comment: ... have you tried changing the last argument of vlookup from False to True?